# Contact-Form HTML / PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, email, post

I put my website on a server and for test the contact-form. I have a line which said me the mail is send but in my mail i never get the mail, then i don't understand what is wrong in my code. Can you help me please ?

PHP Contact Form:

http://www.noelshack.com/2017-36-3-1504703208-capture4.png

Html Contact-Form:

http://www.noelshack.com/2017-36-3-1504703215-capture5.png

Sorry it's my first time and i dont understand how to put code in the editor...

Thx for your comprehension

Comment: "Sorry it's my first time and i dont understand how to put code in the editor...!" Insert your code highlight it and press ctrl+K

Comment: How do you expect us to work with images of code? and Lord only knows when those will expire.

Comment: In any which case, consult the duplicate this was closed with. It contains all of the proper syntax.

Comment: Yes sorry, my bad you can close the ticket if you need it, Aakash Martand explain my misstake

Answer (score 0):

PHP `mail()` function accepts 4 arguments but you're passing 5.
Remove `$enterprise` from `mail()` function as this is invalid argument.
Refer to http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Really thanx you

Comment: Glad this helped you. Consider accepting the answer. Cheers.